# Java and PHP sessions

Tags: java, php, icedtea

I'm creating a Java applet which communicate with my PHP website by requesting pages and retrieving their contents. It works pretty well, and it allows my applet to use PHP sessions.

However, I tried to launch the applet with Opera (instead of Firefox), and it appears that Opera doesn't let my applet use its PHP session, and as Java (or at least [IcedTea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IcedTea)) doesn't handle PHP sessions itself, I can't make my applet work.

Is there any way to make Java be able to handle PHP sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to carry the PHP session ID in every query. That is, make a `start_session.php` which returns only the result of `session_start();` and `echo session_id()` and use that number in the subsequent queries, that is, `other.php?sid=XXXXX`  inside `other.php` use `session_id($_GET['sid']);` to start the session.

Comment: Thanks, I'll search about PHP's session functions :D